# How can I implement closures in C?

Tags: python, c, closures, higher-order-functions, currying

I want to implement the following function in c. I have written three different programming language's implementations of the function:

###### Python

```py
def get_add(x):
    def add(y):
        return x + y
    return add

add5 = get_add(5)
add5(10) # 15
add10 = get_add(10)
add10(10) # 20
```

###### JS

```js
function get_add(x) {
    return (y)=>{
        return x + y
    }
}

add5 = get_add(5)
add5(10) // 15
add10 = get_add(10)
add10(10) // 20
```

###### lua

```lua
function get_add(num)
    return function(a) return a+num end
end

add5 = get_add(5)
add5(10) -- 15
add10 = get_add(10)
add10(10) -- 20
```

I cannot think of a way to implement this. Maybe this can be implemented using hash table in some manner? Or function pointers?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't implement a higher order function transparently in C. I'm prepared to be proven wrong, of course...

Comment: Don't bother doing this in C. If you have such needs, pick another language.

Comment: C doesn't have any kind of "lambda" or higher-order functions (as mentioned). You can possibly use normal functions and functions pointers.

Comment: [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) has something it calls closures, and I've gotten them to work, but I'm not sure how you'd use them to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be fairly confident in the claim that there is no way to do this portably in strictly conforming C. That said, if you're willing to make some generous assumptions about how the specific implementation you're using works, you could do this by allocating memory for new code (or at least the data the closure would capture), marking it as executable, and then engaging in some standards-violating pointer casting. An example that at least works on my machine (x86-64 Linux) would be:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>

uint8_t (*add(uint8_t x))(uint8_t) {
    // lea eax, [rdi + x]
    // ret
    char code[] = { 0x8D, 0x47, x, 0xC3 };
    char *p = mmap(0, sizeof code, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
                   -1, 0);
    memcpy(p, code, sizeof code);
    return (uint8_t(*)(uint8_t))p;
}

int main(void) {
    uint8_t (*add5)(uint8_t) = add(5);
    printf(" 5 + 10 = %" PRIu8 "\n", add5(10));
    printf("10 + 10 = %" PRIu8 "\n", add(10)(10));
    return 0;
}
```

But as noted, this is non-portable at best, and is definitely not anywhere close to idiomatic C.

There are ways to do equivalent things to this in a standards-conforming manner, like storing the data you would capture in a struct and passing that to a different function, but in terms of doing it transparently with functions, I think this is about the best you can do.

---

> So is there any other way to implement it?

Yes, but without external dependencies it can begin to get a little unwieldy.

One option is something like this, where for each different function you create a struct with all the variables you would want to capture and pass that as an argument:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct add {
    uint8_t x;
};

struct add get_add(uint8_t x) {
    return (struct add) {
        .x = x,
    };
}

uint8_t add(struct add info, uint8_t y) {
    return info.x + y;
}

int main(void) {
    struct add add5 = get_add(5);
    printf(" 5 + 10 = %" PRIu8 "\n", add(add5, 10));
    printf("10 + 10 = %" PRIu8 "\n", add(get_add(10), 10));
    return 0;
}
```

This becomes a bit verbose if you want a function that has more than a couple curried arguments.

---

@SteveSummit's suggestion in the comments about libffi is also good. With their closures API, here's an example of what you might want:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ffi.h>

void _add(ffi_cif *cif, void *ret, void *args[], void *x) {
    *(ffi_arg*)ret = *(uint64_t*)x + *(uint64_t*)args[0];
}

int main(void) {
    ffi_cif cif;
    ffi_type *args[1];
    void *add_code;
    ffi_closure *add_closure = ffi_closure_alloc(sizeof *add_closure, &add_code);
    uint64_t x = 5;

    if (add_closure) {
        args[0] = &ffi_type_uint64;
        if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, 1, &ffi_type_uint64, args) == FFI_OK) {
            if (ffi_prep_closure_loc(add_closure, &cif, _add, &x, add_code) == FFI_OK) {
                printf(" 5 + 10 = %" PRIu64 "\n", ((uint64_t (*)(uint64_t))add_code)(10));
                printf(" 5 + 15 = %" PRIu64 "\n", ((uint64_t (*)(uint64_t))add_code)(15));
            }
        }
    }

    ffi_closure_free(add_closure);

    return 0;
}
```

I haven't checked, but my guess is their implementation is probably just a more robust wrapper around the first example I give (with additional platform support).

Comment: The solution works great in Linux. Thank You. But my actual work machine is windows (Visual Studio 2019 for compiler).  The example I gave was a simple example of adding or incrementing a number. But the actual inner function I am implementing in my project is quite complex than incrementing a given number. So is there any other way to implement it? "There are ways to do equivalent things to this in a standards-conforming manner" can you give example for this. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It is rare for me to say this, @VipulCariappa, but you may be looking for C++ instead of C.  Especially so since you are programming for Windows, which is very much C++-centric, using Microsoft's compiler, which has somewhat idiomatic C support.

Comment: @VipulCariappa I didn't say this explicitly in my answer, but this does sound like an XY problem. This kind of design is not common in C, so I would make sure that you (a) want to structure whatever you're doing like this, and (b) use C. One of those is probably not the best choice.